# $GL_1(\mathcal{E}'(\mathbb{R}))$ open in $\mathcal{E}'(\mathbb{R})$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, schwartz-distributions, topological-vector-spaces

Let $\mathcal{E}'(\mathbb{R})$ be algebra of all compactly supported distributions on $\mathbb{R}$, equipped with the strong dual  topology $\beta(\mathcal{E}',\mathcal{E})$, and with the usual operations of addition and convolution.

Is the set ${{\textrm{GL}}}_1(\mathcal{E}'(\mathbb{R}))$ of invertible elements open in $\mathcal{E}'(\mathbb{R})$?

(As an example of an element in ${{\textrm{GL}}}_1(\mathcal{E}'(\mathbb{R}))$ which does not have support $\{0\}$, we have that $\delta_n$ belongs to ${{\textrm{GL}}}_1(\mathcal{E}'(\mathbb{R}))$ 
because $\delta_n \ast \delta_{-n}=\delta_0$.)

Comment: Which invertible distributions do you know? Doesn't the Theorem of supports (the convex hull of the support of the convolution is the sum of the convex hulls of the supports of the factors) imply that an invertible distribution hat support $\{0\}$?

Comment: Sorry, not $\{0\}$ but a singleton.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps Jochen Wengenroth's comments already give the answer, but here's a direct argument.

By [Paley-Wiener](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paley%E2%80%93Wiener_theorem) for distributions, the Fourier transform $\tilde{\Delta}(k)$ of a distribution of compact support $\Delta(x) \in \mathcal{E}'(\mathbb{R})$ is entire, of exponential type, with at most asymptotic polynomial growth on the real axis. Since convolutions become products under the Fourier transform, $\Delta(x) \in \mathrm{GL}_1(\mathcal{E}'(\mathbb{R}))$ only if $\tilde{\Delta}(k)$ is pointwise invertible and $\tilde{\Delta}(k)^{-1}$ has the same analytic properties. But by the [Hadamard factorization theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_factorization_theorem#Hadamard_factorization_theorem) this can only be if $\tilde{\Delta}(k) = e^{i k c_1 + c_0}$, with $c_1 \in \mathbb{R}$, $c_0\in \mathbb{C}$. So indeed, $\mathrm{GL}_1(\mathcal{E}'(\mathbb{R}))$ consists only of scaled translates of $\delta_0$.

I'm no big expert on the topology of $\mathcal{E}'(\mathbb{R})$, but I suspect this set is too small to be open.